# Override the JavaScripted style with media query

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

In my page design, I have put a menu button on the small resolutions, which onclick I show the menu items. If the items are in the show state (which is done by JS) and I maximize the browser (it would change to another query conditions) the items did not hide. Even I add the display:none to the css to hide them, but it did not hide. To overcome I put !important there. But it caused another issue: the menu items would not shown by the menu click.
It is appreciated if someone could help me.
***Edit*** for better understanding.
The menu click js is as following:

```
$("#mobilemenu").click(function(){
   var dis = $("#menuitems li").css('display');
   if(dis == 'none') {
      $("#menuitems li").slideDown("slow");}
   else {
     $("#menuitems li").slideUp("slow");
   }
});
```

On my media query:

```
@media {
   #menuitems li {display:none;}
}
```

And on the main css:

```
#menuitems li {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than directly setting the style in your JavaScript code, you should instead give the element a class which allows it to be styled with CSS.

For example, instead of directly setting `display: block`, you can show the element like this:

#### JavaScript

```
myElem.className = 'show';
```

#### CSS

```css
myElem.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Then with your media query, you can simply override this:

#### CSS

```css
@media screen {
    myElem.show {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I have edited my question and added the codes. Could you please take a look to see if it should changed to what you said?

Comment: jQuery's `slideDown()` method directly sets `display: block`. You'll need to replace `slideDown()` with something else. (E.g. a CSS class styled to increase an element's height with a transition).